# Problems with degrees Celsius in new siunitx

Tags: siunitx

There have been some changes to `siunitx` recently and one of them is the typesetting of units. The change is most noticeable in degrees Celsius.

In the new version, the degree symbol no longer scales well with the rest of the text. You can see this in the following example.

```
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{15}{\celsius}{\tiny\SI{15}{\celsius}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

PS: **very important**: if you decide to redefine `\celsius` as suggested in the answer, do not forget to redefine `\degree` as well for consistency:

```
\DeclareSIUnit[quantity-product = ]\degree{\text{\textdegree}}
```

Comment: BTW, by 'new' I assume you mean v3.x series, so from mid-2021 onward

Comment: @JosephWright Quite possibly.  I don't write a new book each year so it takes me some time to notice a difference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard settings in `siunitx` do their best to select something sensible based on a 'reference rendering'. Here, you are in math mode and have no Unicode math code loaded, so the reference for the degree symbol is `{}^{\circ}` If you try that in your demo, you'll find it comes out at the same size you have. You may prefer the text mode `\textdegree` or if appropriate direct use of `°` (if you load `unicode-math` with a suitable font, for example).

---

In general terms, the approach expected by `siunitx` is that you make an appropriate font choice for your document and adjust the definitions as required to make that work.

The alternative approach is to  is essentially to change the definition of the relevant unit. That seems to be the desired outcome here, using the text mode symbol (`\textdegree`) even in math mode, so

```latex
\DeclareSIUnit\degreeCelsius{\text{\textdegree}C}
```

would work.

(Depending on the font setup available, of course, it may be necessary to adjust both as `siunitx` may simply 'guess wrong' in terms of unit definitions.)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151500/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-problems-with-degrees-celsius-in-new-siuni); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.